# Linq to Entities - Eager Loading

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a complex object and when I use a linq query without the Include syntax, I am still getting all the related entities back in my object graph. Wha can explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You aren't really. Linq loads the objects as you need them, but it does it tranparently so as soon as you start to browse the objects (either in code or in a debugger watch) it loads them so it looks as though you have them all there already.</strike>

If you perform the query and then kill the connection to the database you will get database exceptions when you try and browse the objects as it will be unable to load them.

Edit: Sorry, I Misread the question. Linq-to-entities does not support lazy loading (See comment from Craig below). To get the full object graph you should either use "Include" in the Linq query or call Load() on each reference. Sorry, I cannot explain the behaviour described in the question. Can you give some more detail. Perhaps post your query and code.

Comment: This answer reads as though LINQ to Entities was doing lazy loading. Perhaps that is not what was intended, but that's how I read the text here. In fact, LINQ to Entities does not do lazy loading (unless you are using version 4 and specifically enable it). It's hard to say more without seeing the actual query.

Comment: Ahh. Good point, I just saw Linq and thought Linq-to-SQL (Which works as described in my answer). Yes, you are right Craig, Linq to Entities does not do Lazy loading. You either have to use "Include" or call Load() on the references. In this case I cannot explain the behaviour described in the Question.

Comment: In fairness, it's hard to say why a query behaves the way it does without seeing the query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using Entity Framework 4 and lazy lading is enabled. You can check the  ObjectContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled property on your context. Although the property is 'false' by default, the model generation tools normally set it to 'true'. Check the [MSDN article on Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) - the section on lazy loading explains this.